# Unable to DB2 Coalesce

Tags: db2

I am trying to have a "0" show up if there is no result in a DB2 query.  Coalesce is not working for me.  This is DB2 LUW v8.2.  How can I do this?

```
SELECT 'Stuff',
COALESCE((SUM(OI.QUANTITY)),0)
FROM DB2ADMIN.ORDERS O INNER JOIN DB2ADMIN.ORDERITEMS OI ON O.ORDERS_ID = OI.ORDERS_ID
WHERE DATE(O.TIMEPLACED) = (DATE(CURRENT DATE) - 1 DAYS)
AND OI.CATENTRY_ID = 000001    
GROUP BY DATE(O.TIMEPLACED)
```

Comment: It may be helpful if you explain *why* `COALESCE` "is not working".  What results are you getting?  What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z_createcte.htm) to do this.

```
WITH MYCTE (MYSTUFF, MYSUM) AS (
SELECT 'Stuff',0
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Stuff', SUM(OI.QUANTITY)
FROM DB2ADMIN.ORDERS O INNER JOIN DB2ADMIN.ORDERITEMS OI ON O.ORDERS_ID = OI.ORDERS_ID
WHERE DATE(O.TIMEPLACED) = (DATE(CURRENT DATE) - 1 DAYS)
AND OI.CATENTRY_ID = 000001    
GROUP BY DATE(O.TIMEPLACED))
SELECT MYSTUFF, SUM(MYSUM)          
FROM MYCTE
GROUP BY MYSTUFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely the Coalesce is working but the sum is failing because of null, did you try to use COALESCE OR NVL inside the SUM ? i.e.

```
SELECT 'Stuff',
(SUM(COALESCE(OI.QUANTITY,0)))
FROM DB2ADMIN.ORDERS O INNER JOIN DB2ADMIN.ORDERITEMS OI ON O.ORDERS_ID = OI.ORDERS_ID
WHERE DATE(O.TIMEPLACED) = (DATE(CURRENT DATE) - 1 DAYS)
AND OI.CATENTRY_ID = 000001    
GROUP BY DATE(O.TIMEPLACED)
```